# Javascript - create html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, for-loop, parse-platform

I am working with Parse API (parse.com), and I am having a lot of trouble integrating a function into a for loop. I am trying to pass down the for loop variable "k" into the function, but it won't seem to work. I can't seem to access the "k" variable down under the parse success function. Can someone please help me?

Here is my code:

```
function checkStock () {
    for(k=0; k<productNum; k++) {

        var usersID = parseJson.Products[k].userID;

        var NikeLogins = Parse.Object.extend("NikeLogins");
        var query = new Parse.Query(NikeLogins);
        query.get(usersID, {
            success: function(NikeLogins) {
                var score = NikeLogins.get("inStock");
                if (score == false) {
                    alert(k);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this always showing k to be productNum's value this is probably because you are capturing k  in a loop where you are defining a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to close around it with another function.

```
function checkStock () {
    for(k=0; k<productNum; k++) {
        (function(k) {
          var usersID = parseJson.Products[k].userID;

          var NikeLogins = Parse.Object.extend("NikeLogins");
          var query = new Parse.Query(NikeLogins);
          query.get(usersID, {
              success: function(NikeLogins) {
                  var score = NikeLogins.get("inStock");
                  if (score == false) {
                    alert(k);
                  }
              }
          });
        })(k);
    }
}
```

Comment: A little new to javascript. Can you please show me an example? much appreciated.

Comment: @RobertChristopher updated - read up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1